# Generating pronounceable digrams in Python

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, linguistics

I am generating all two letter (digram) combinations of the standard alphabet

```
import string
import itertools
UPPERCASE_ALPHABET = string.ascii_uppercase
TWO_LETTER_PERMS = itertools.permutations(UPPERCASE_ALPHABET, 2)
```

By using the 650 generated digrams in a search application of drug names,I am finding that some of them always retrieve no results probably being not pronounceable.

For example "ZQ" or "KM" (just as an example). While I do understand that each language might carry some differences, at least for English is there a way to judge if a generated digram is pronounceable?

Comment: I have no trouble pronouncing either *ZQ* (sounds a little like *zuk*) or *KM* (*kum*).  I'm not sure you'll find any way to judge if a digram is pronounceable, I think you'll come closest by finding those digrams which don't occur in a corpus of English words.  *ZQ* - I can't think of any examples, *KM* I can think immediately of *booKMaker* maybe others if I had more time to spare

Comment: Good point. Thanks